# I want to display all the comments of one particular product in magento

Tags: magento-1.9.1

I want to display all the comments of one particular product in magento. For example for Each Product it have to show the comments of that particular product only.

Comment: please someone tell me the solution for that...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the Reviews on the product page you can use the code below:

Step 1. You have to edit the catalog.xml file you can find it by navigating to the app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/layout/catalog.xml

Step 2. Add this block under the catalog_product_view

```
<block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.info.product_additional_data" as="product_review" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
</block>
```

Step 3. Now call this particular block into the view.phtml page you can find it by navigating to the app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Step 4. Add this chunk of the code where you want to display the review on this page

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_review') ?>
```

That's it hope it helps.

Thanks